# Android Invalid Int error when parsing number from text file

Tags: java, android, integer

I have a .txt in my website that contains a number (in this case 3) and I use this code to check whether this number is greater than or less than another number, but the code gives me this error:

```
03-03 16:27:43.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.downloadingprogressbar/com.example.downloadingprogressbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3
```

This is my code:

```
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://mywebsite.org/version.txt");
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line + "\n");
        }
        String casa = new String(total.toString());

        //boolean version = (casa>4);
        if (Integer.parseInt(casa)>4){
            risposta.setText("la tua versione è aggiornata");
        }
        else {
            risposta.setText("aggiorna la tua versione");
        }
```

Comment: Your `String` `casa` doesn't just contain the number `3`, it also may contain multiple new line `\n` characters, which cannot be parsed into numbers.

Comment: `String casa  = EntityUtils.toString(ht)`. And remove the while-loop, without appending \n

Comment: I forget to remove the while because it's only one line. It's my mistake I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Kon, your variable "casa" is containing another characters.

Try using the `trim()` method:

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(casa.trim())>4){
...
...
...
```

but now i see that you are appending the "\n", in total variable, is this "new line" necessary?:

```
 while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove all whitespace that might be surrounding your number:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(casa.trim()) > 4){
    // ...
}
```